# Generate Network plot from dataframe

Tags: python, graph, networkx, graphviz

Suppose I have this dataframe where column `a-number` represents nodes with directed edges to nodes in `b-number`:

```
    a_number    b_number
0   343              991
1   991              633
2   343              633
3   633              628
4   343              633
5   628              916
6   697              886
7   916              572
8   697              884
9   886              125
```

How can I generate an image representation of this graph that looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networkx is the go-to library for graphs in python:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html

First do the import:

```
import networkx as nx
```

To start a graph like that declare a inicialize DiGraph (directed graph):

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
```

Then add some nodes:

```
G.add_node(343)
G.add_node(991)
G.add_node(633)
```

Then some edges:

```
G.add_edge(343,991)
G.add_edge(991,633)
G.add_edge(343,633)
```

Finaly draw the graph G:

```
nx.draw(G, with_labels = True, font_size=14 , node_size=2000)
```

use the with_labels = True so you can have the node numbers, node_size=2000 to make the nodes bigger and  font_size=14 to make the font also bigger

This is the output of the code:

[image: This is the output of the code]

Now to read from the dataframe, just do a cycle like:

```
for  i, (x, y) in df.iterrows():
    G.add_node(x)
    G.add_node(y)
    G.add_edge(x,y)
```

If the nodes or edges already exists it will not add a new one, so you don't need to worry about it

Comment: how to automatically read from the input dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [`graphviz`](https://pypi.org/project/graphviz/) library:

```
from graphviz import Digraph
dot = Digraph()

for i, (a, b) in df.iterrows():
    dot.edge(str(a), str(b))
    
dot.render('graph.gv', view=True)
```

Comment: can you add an image?